# jmeter+influxdb Backend Listener: howto specify password?

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, jmeter-plugins

I use Jmeter Backend Listener url:

`influxdbUrl = http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8086/write?db=JMeter&u=jusr&p=C-UBBC-"<`

I get an error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed calling setupTest Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 76: http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8086/write?db=JMeter&u=jusr&p=C-UBBC-"<`

Problem in special characters in password: `C-UBBC-"<`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every character is allowed in an URL, you can use alphanumeric and few special ones, in particular `; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #`. Everything else needs to be [percent-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Wrap your password into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) and it should resolve your issue.

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)